# Natural exact sequence of Selmer groups

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, exact-sequence, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over number field $K$.
Let $\phi:E \to E'$ be an isogeny,
and $\hat{\phi}$ be its dual isogeny.

Then, there is natural exact sequence between Selmer group, $Sel[\phi]\to Sel[2]\to Sel[\hat{\phi}]$
(Take long exact sequence Galois cohomology from short exact sequence
($　0\to{E[\phi]}\to E[2]\to E[\hat{\phi}]$).

Why is the first map injective ?
(Taking $1$-st Galois cohomology of $　0\to{E[\phi]}\to E[2]\to E[\hat{\phi}]$, I gain $0\to{E[\phi]}\to E[2]\to E[\hat{\phi}]\to H^1(G_K,E[\phi])\to H^1(G_K,E[2])\to..$
Why is $H^1(G_K,E[\phi])\to H^1(G_K,E[2])$ injective ?)

P.S

Silverman's book, 'The arithmetic of elliptic curves', p$350$, $4$-th line from the bottom, there is exact sequence of Tate-Shafarevich group. This question is essentially the same as asking why there is the exact sequence of $p350$, $4$-th line from the bottom.

Comment: $\phi$ is a $2$-isogeny? The first map is not injective in general. Its kernel is $E'[\hat\phi](\mathbb Q)/ \phi(E[2](\mathbb Q))$.

Comment: If $\phi$ is 2-sigeony, is it injective ?

Comment: It's only because $\phi$ is a $2$-isogeny that you get a map to $\mathrm{Sel}(2)$ at all. It's only injective if that kernel is zero, which need not be the case.